# Sorting a PHP array fetched through a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am populating a select option using a php while loop from a mysql table.  The following is the php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$database = $_POST['folder'];
include('connect.php');
$connect = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password,$database );

if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
}

$result = $connect->query("select name from treeview where parent_id = 1;");

?>

<option value="">Select Location</option>
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1['name'];?>"><?php echo $row1['name'];?></option>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

This works correctly, except for the fact that the fetched items are not sorted alphabetically.  I understand this could be trivial, but I couldn't get it right.  I tried the following:

Option 1

```
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
    $row1 = sort($row1);
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row1['name'];?>"><?php echo $row1['name'];?></option>
```

Option 2:

```
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;?>
    <option value="<?php echo sort($row1['name']);?>"><?php echo sort($row1['name']);?></option>
```

Both didn't work.

Comment: _“Both didn't work.”_ - both make little sense. _Inside_ your loop, you are only dealing with one row at a time. You can “sort” one single item all day long as you want, that won’t change anything. You need to sort the whole result _before_ you output it in a loop - ideally directly in the database query that fetches this data to begin with. That is done using an `ORDER BY` clause - go read up on that, if you are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: @misorude  Thank you order by did help. Can accept this as my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your SQL query and use ORDER BY

See here [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to sort a single row, instead of between the rows. Sorting all the rows will require you to fetch them all of them and then sort them. An easier approach, IMHO, would be to sort them in the query itself:

```
$result = $connect->query("select name from treeview where parent_id = 1 ORDER BY 1;");
# Here ------------------------------------------------------------------^
```